# plugin/docker : Is passing id_rsa priv key using build_args correct?

Tags: docker, drone.io

**Secret**

I added a secret to drone.io using:

`drone org secret add --image=* --conceal --skip-verify=true octocat SSH_KEY @/home/me/.ssh/id_rsa`

**Dockerfile**

Because `npm install` needs to access private repositories, I specify an **ARG** in my Dockerfile, to get my private ssh_key:

```
FROM node:latest

ARG SSH_KEY

ENV SSH_KEY=$SSH_KEY

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh && \
    echo $SSH_KEY | cut -d "\"" -f 2 > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 0600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    eval `ssh-agent -s` && \
    ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**.drone.yml**

And finally, in my `.drone.yml` pipeline, on the `plugin/docker` step, I use build-arg to inject the ssk_key:

```
pipeline:
  test:
    image: node:latest
    commands:
      - mkdir /root/.ssh && echo "$SSH_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && chmod 0600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
      - eval `ssh-agent -s` && ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa
      - echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config
      - npm install
      - npm test
  docker:
    image: plugins/docker
    repo: octocat/bar
    tags: latest
    build_args:
      - SSH_KEY=${SSH_KEY}
```

**My questions:**

1. Is that the correct way to inject my ssh key to the Dockerfile, from drone pipeline?
2. the build_args are printed in the frontend logs, so is the SSK_KEY...how to avoid this?
3. the build args is passing my SSK_KEY + quotes around it -> "SSH_KEY", so I have to remove the quotes in my Dockerfile (by piping the string) before echoing it to `/root/.ssh/id_rsa:`, any way to not have these `"`?

Many Thanks!!

[EDIT] thanks to Adrian for suggesting a better way, remove the `npm install` from Dockerfile, as the `node_modules` can be shared through a volume between the pipeline steps.

Comment: Could you copy in the npm modules rather than run `npm install` in the Dockerfile? I think that would be easier and cleaner

Comment: @AdrianMouat I just removed the ```npm install``` from my Dockerfile thinking that is was redundant, and suddenly understood the meaning of your comment :D much better indeed, thanks

Comment: @Sulliwane note that if you use git+https urls in your package.json instead of git+ssh, you don't need the ssh key. Drone will automatically configure your environment with a .netrc file which will automatically authenticate http requests. And +1 to just copying your node_modules into your docker image ... I would have advised the exact same.

Comment: off-topic, regarding copying the node_modules vs doing the `npm install`. Wouldn't that imply that node_modules should be under version control?